# Как сделать прогресс бар?

Tags: javascript

Вот мне интересно, как сделать прогресс-бар? Например я загружаю фотографию и вижу счётчик процентов загрузки. Как это вообще сделать? А именно хотелось бы увидеть просто алгоритм.

Comment: Тысяча раз сделали до вас. 
http://www.webappers.com/2007/07/31/webappers-simple-ajax-progress-bar-with-css/ Вот пример пятилетней давности.

Comment: Для загрузки фоток с пк, нужен флеш что бы отобразить прогресс загрузки, или как вариант можно посмотреть http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: Флеш? Для прогресс-бара? Какой год то, а?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Писать вручную обработку загрузки файла очень долгая и трудная затея.
Когда то писал скрипт на html 5 для загрузки файлов любого размера на сервер.
Очень много кода и проблем.

Если вам это срочно нужно по работе, то выход только 1 это идти к фрилансерам.

Если же это ради интереса то использовать следует HTML5 File API.
Вот код который при загрузке файла в браузер покажет его содержимое. Проверять надо в разных браузерах.
Дальше уже имя содержимое файла его через ajax передавать.

```
<!-- Форма загрузки файла-->
<form id="meta">
<div><input type="file" id="files" onload="получить_файл()" name="file"></div>
</form>

<script>
function получить_файл(){
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change',function(e){
// Ни одного файла не выбрано
if(!e.target.files.length)
{
alert('Выберите файла!');
return;
}

// Берем первый файл.
первый_файл = e.target.files[0];
var имя_файла = первый_файл.name;
var тип_файла = первый_файл.type; // может и не определить так что не используй
var размер_файла_в_байтах = первый_файл.size;

alert('\nимя файла=' + имя_файла +'\nтип_файла=' + тип_файла + '\nРазмер файла=' + размер_файла_в_байтах);

var чтение_файла = new FileReader();  
var конец_резки =  первый_файл.size; 
var блок_резки = первый_файл.mozSlice(0, конец_резки); // в будущем посмотреть на mozSlice != slice
чтение_файла.readAsBinaryString(блок_резки); //  readAsDataURL   // readAsBinaryString

// вот здесь загрузка файла в браузер и показ содержимого
чтение_файла.onload = function(e)
{
alert ("\nсодержимое: \n\n" + чтение_файла.result);
};

});
}
получить_файл();
</script>
```

Comment: Ребят, мне нужно узнать, как вычислять % загрузки и всё. Загрузил фотографию например и узнать, на сколько % она загружена.

Comment: У вас сама загрузка уже работает? 
Или вы хотите чтобы мы узнали как загрузить изображение, как получить состояние загрузки от javascript и как вычислить длину полоски исходя из этих данных?

Comment: @manking Вот именно этого и хочет узнать 99% людей. Я гугл вывернул на изнанку что бы этого узнать, но так и не вышло. Если есть хоть какой то рабочий примерчик, подскажи пожалуйста !!!

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться html5-им прогресс баром http://htmlbook.ru/html/progress + ajax. Ну конечно смотря как вы загружаете файл, у некоторых библиотек отсылается % загрузки

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сначала с этим разобраться: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#default. Иногда лучше понять сам смысл происходящего, потом можно свои прогрессбары лепить, только мозк включить.