# Как асинхронно передать файл на сервер?

Tags: javascript, html, php

Как асинхронно передать файл размером больше 10mb на сервер?

Comment: Создаете на странице фрейм с выбором файла. Пользователь выбирает файл и нажимает отправить. Отправка начинается в фрейме, а на главной странице начинаете крутить спиннер.  
Либо с помощью flash это делать.  
По другому никак.

Comment: Автор видимо говорит о блокировке сайта у пользователя, возникающей в результате загрузки файла. Если это так, то обычно загрузку файлов прикручивают на другой домен (субдомен).

Comment: в iframe влезает до 2 mb

Comment: > в iframe влезает до 2 mb

чиво ? настройки на сервере смотрите

Comment: в php.ini переменая post_max_size: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
Если вы сидите на чюжом хостинге Flash вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть доступ к php.ini то нужно увеличить лимиты post_max_size и upload_max_filesize.

Если нет, то попробуйте это сделать, создав в корне веб-пространства файл .htaccess и запишите в него

```
php_value post_max_size 12M
php_value upload_max_filesize 12M
```

12 это с запасом (на всякий случай).

С сервером закончили. Нужно сделать ajax загрузку файла. Вот [тут](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/10example-ajax-upload-file-with-php.html) 10 примером как это сделать с помощью php. Я бы использовал первый.

Answer (score 0):

Файл нужно резать на куски.
С помощью HTML 5.

В начале файл подгружается в браузер. Там он режется на несколько кусков. Затем каждый кусок передаётся на сервер, где они склеиваются. Когда передача завершена файл сохраняется с нужным расширением.

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146938/js-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80) уже отвечал на подобное.